# Recursive reading on all files in a directory - FileSystem API

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I am getting confuse how to read a list of files recursively.
Assume I have 3 text files in my filesytem api root directory

- text1.txt
- text2.txt
- text3.txt

My goal is to read each text files one by one and then concatenate all the entries in each file into one string but I am currently at lost
how to do this in Javascript FileSystem API.

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
function onInitFs(fs) {
  var dirReader = fs.root.createReader();
  var entries = [];

  // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
  var readEntries = function() {
     dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
      if (!results.length) {
        readAllFiles(results);
      } else {
        entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
        readEntries();
      }
    }, errorHandler);
  };
  readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.
}

function readAllFiles(entries){
    //Loop thru all the files and read each entries
}
```

I have seen how to read one text file but I dont know how to implement the reading of all files and concatenate the value.
They all implement callback functions so I am getting confused on how to handle it.  Any points please?

I actually have been basing all my works in this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem

**UPDATE 2**
As per @Johan
I actually changed my code to make use of callback

```
 window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
    function onInitFs(fs) {
      var dirReader = fs.root.createReader();
      var entries = [];

      // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
      var readEntries = function() {
         dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
          if (!results.length) {
            readAllFiles(results, concatMessages);
          } else {
            entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
            readEntries();
          }
        }, errorHandler);
      };
      readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.
    }


    var concatMessage = '';

    function concatMessages(message){
        concatMessage += message;
    }

    function readAllFiles(logs, callBack) { 
        logs.forEach(function(entry, iCtr) {
            var message;

            entry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    //message += this.result;
                    if(callBack)
                        callBack('==================' + iCtr + '==========================');
                        callBack(this.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file); // Read the file as plaintext.
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

        });

    }
```

My only problem is this, the callback function is not sequential.
It reads text2.txt first then text3.txt then text1.txt so the end result is not sequential which is not what I want to do.  Any more hints?

Comment: Hmm, isn't your code fully recursive on all paths? What would make your function exit?

Comment: @Johan Ooopss..sorry.. fixed my code.  After you have access to the files, I want to read each file one by one and concantenate the entries.  In the readAllFiles, I am getting confused on how to read each file since the FileSystem API is composed of lots of callback and I am having problem how to concatenate the result.

Comment: I would make use of promises. Not sure how many browsers that support it yet but you could always include jQuery

Comment: If you don't want to use a library, use a callback with 2 parameters: file number and the text. Wait for all to complete and concatinate the string

Comment: @Johan, I actually tried a callback as per your advise.  Can you check my Update 2? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend you consider using something like caolan's [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) library to accomplish this.

You can do something like this:

```
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

    // Perform operation on file here.
    console.log('Processing file ' + file);
    callback();
}, function(err) {
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if (err) {
        // One of the iterations produced an error.
        // All processing will now stop.
        console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
        // do your concatenation here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was glad that you understand what I am trying to do.  But unfortunately, its not possible for me to use 3rd party library as of the moment.  This is a case of asynchronous processing but my javascript knowledge isn't that far ahead.

Comment: You can google around to find some similar examples of how to use `forEach` and write a promise callback. No need to use a 3rd party library in that case.